# How to center-align auto-generated HTML table with CSS only?

Tags: css, html-table

I have tables in an HTML file that are automatically generated from Markdown tables (I use R package **bookdown** to create a GitBook). I want several conditions to be met on my website:

1. A table should be center-aligned if it is smaller than the width of the page.
2. If a table is extremely wide and does not fit into a page, the table should have an individual x-axis scrollbar that moves the table only (see the example below). This condition should apply for each overflowed table.
3. The widths of the table captions should span 100% of the window's width despite the width of the table (as they are in the example below).

Currently, conditions 2 and 3 are met but I get tables that are left-aligned. As HTML is auto-generated, all I can do is to create a custom CSS file and modify it (I cannot modify HTML).

**Question:** How can I get center-aligned tables by modifying CSS only?

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```css
table {
    display: block;
    margin: 25px auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table caption {
  display: block;
}

table caption span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td, table th {
    padding: 0px 15px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #fbeecb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  
  <table>
    <caption>
      <span id="tab:tbl-1">Table 15.1: </span>
      Table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption.
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header"><th align="right">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th><th align="right">y</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>164.2</td><td>1.876087608760</td></tr>
      <tr><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td></tr>
      <tr><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td></tr>
      <tr><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <caption>
      <span id="tab:tbl-2">Table 15.2: </span>
      Table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
      table caption, table caption, table caption.
    </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.876087608760</td></tr>
      <tr><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td></tr>
      <tr><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td></tr>
      <tr><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use css  `caption-side: top-outside;`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 2em auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  caption-side: top-outside;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  height: 1em;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  text-align: right;
}
table caption span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #fbeecb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption> <span id="tab:tbl-1">Table 15.1: </span> 
    Table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
    table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
    table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption,
    table caption, table caption, table caption.</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr class="header"><th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th><th>y</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>164.2</td><td>1.876087608760</td></tr>
    <tr><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td></tr>
    <tr><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td></tr>
    <tr><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `caption-side: top-outside;` is only supported by FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `display: block` to any table tags, tables have `display: table` by default. Those styles imbue unique behavior to the table tags which make them more than just a div (which is basically what a tag is when it has `display: block`).

The attribute `align` (ex. `<th align="right">...`) is deprecated -- use `style="text-align: right"` instead.

After the conflicting `display: block` styles are removed -- `margin: 25px auto;` centers all of the tables.

The caption by default cannot exceed the width of the table unless [`caption-side: top-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side#bcd:css.properties.caption-side#Values) is used. Unfortunately, that only works for [Firefox browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caption-side#bcd:css.properties.caption-side). The only valid solution would be to place a block tag outside of the table.

Because of varying widths of the tables, each one needs to be wrapped in a block tag and then everything wrapped in another block element.

I had the same problem at work -- the back end dynamically generated these ugly tables to which I had no control over. The only solution is to apply JavaScript after the tables were rendered. The following demo has the necessary JavaScript to meet all objectives with valid (but ugly) HTML and CSS.

---

#### Demo

```js
/*
Insert <main> into <body>
*/
const main = document.createElement('main');
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', main);

/*
Wrap a <section> around each <table> and insert each <section> into <main>
*/
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('table');
tabs.forEach(t => {
  const sec = document.createElement('section');
  t.parentNode.insertBefore(sec, t);
  sec.appendChild(t);
  document.querySelector('main').insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', sec);
});

/*
Create and insert a <div class='caption'> above each <table>
Take the content of the corresponding <caption> and render it into div.caption
remove all <caption>
*/
const caps = document.querySelectorAll('caption');
caps.forEach(cap => {
  let html = `<div class='caption'></div>`;
  cap.closest('table').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
  const newCap = cap.closest('table').previousElementSibling;
  newCap.innerHTML = cap.innerHTML;
  cap.remove();
});

/*
Remove the align attributes from each <th> and add .right class
*/
const rth = document.querySelectorAll('th[align=right]');
rth.forEach(cell => {
  cell.removeAttribute('align');
  cell.classList.add('right');
});
```

```css
main {
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

section {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: min-content;
}

table {
  margin: 25px auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.caption {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.caption span {
  font-weight: bold
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0px 15px;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

table tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #fbeecb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body><table><caption> <span id="tab:tbl-1">Table 15.1: </span>Table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption.X</caption><thead><tr><th align='right'>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th><th align='right'>y</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>164.2</td><td>1.876087608760</td></tr><tr><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td></tr><tr><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td></tr><tr><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td></tr></tbody></table><table><caption> <span id="tab:tbl-2">Table 15.2: </span>Table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption, table caption.</caption><thead><tr><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th><th>x</th><th>y</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.8760</td><td>164.2</td><td>1.876087608760</td></tr><tr><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td><td>118.8</td><td>1.9317</td></tr><tr><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td><td>180.4</td><td>2.0957</td></tr><tr><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td><td>184.0</td><td>2.0969</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```